# Error uploading image via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image via ajax. Javascript is returning "success", but my browser says there is a problem with upload. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<form action="" id="form-new-badge" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input id="new-file-path-static-image" required="required" class="file-path validate" type="file">
</form>

$("#new-file-path-static-image").on("change", function(){
        alert("time to upload");
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        alert(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl + "image/upload",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("success " + data)
            }
        });
    });
```

> code
>   :
>   310
>   description
>   :
>   "There is a problem with the upload."

Comment: Does the file show up in your backend?

Comment: First look : Is apiUrl defined ?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter no.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes, the request is sent successfully.

Comment: This could be a permissions issue on the back end where you are going to place the file that was uploaded.

Comment: PROTIP: You can just use `this` instead of doing `$(this)[0]`.

Comment: You trigger the call to you ajax onchange of a text field ? I don't get it. I think it should be triggered on a "Send" button. And then you retreive the file input data to send it to a PHP script that can handle it. Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: @RocketHazmat already tried it

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it is a input file. I edited it, sorry.

Comment: Where are you seeing that error message?  Also why are you using `async: false`?  Adding that no longer makes this AJAX *asynchronous* and will lock up the browser.  P.S. I suggest `console.log` instead of `alert()`.

Comment: @vbotio: That "PROTIP" above wasn't a suggestion on how to fix the issue, it was just something I wanted to point out.